# $ADB_SERVER_SOCKET

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a question. I was learning how to connect to android emulator from wsl-2. I saw `$ADB_SERVER_SOCKET` variable when looking for a solve way for the problem. I can’t find any information about the variable. Can anyone share a official source about the variable?

Answer (score 3):

`adb` has two parts:

1. adb client - the command-line adb executable you use
2. adb-server - this component is the one talking to your devices. If you execute adb client and the server is not running then it starts it.

Both communicate to each other using TCP. Usually both parts are running on the same computer and even on the same user account.

By using the variable `$ADB_SERVER_SOCKET` you can advice the adb client to connect to an adb-server running somewhere else. As WSL2 is a virtual environment separated from your regular Windows you can use it to advice e.g. adb client inside WSL2 to communicate with adb-server on your Windows machine.

```
export ADB_SERVER_SOCKET=tcp:$WSL_HOST_IP:5037
```

Your WSL_HOST_IP can be found in `/etc/resolv.conf` in the `nameserver` entry<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking)</sup>.

Comment: Thank you. Where did you find the information? Is the information from official documentation? If information is official can you give link of source?

Comment: @ilkinimanov For me this is common knowledge. But most of it should also be documented here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: I looked at this documentation but couldn't find it, so I asked this question

Comment: @ilkinimanov: See [ADB_SERVER_SOCKET usage in source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/adb/client/commandline.cpp;l=1646-1650).